# How should i pass prisma client instance to graphql context?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma

How should i pass prisma client instance to graphql context?

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

// Should i use it like this?
export async function contextResolver(ctx: Ctx): Promise<Ctx> {
  ctx.db = prisma
}

// Or this
export async function contextResolver(ctx: Ctx): Promise<Ctx> {
  ctx.db = new PrismaClient()
}

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: contextResolver
})
```

I'm not sure if in first case my client will be blocked somehow when first request doing transaction and second trying to use same client at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the first one.

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export async function contextResolver(ctx: Ctx): Promise<Ctx> {
  ctx.db = prisma
}
```

It is recommended to have only a single instance of `Prisma` running throughout your application. This will also prevent database connections getting exhausted.